# Error in inserting values

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a piece of code to populate a table and its not working, it keep sending error message like `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`
Here is the table creation on MSSQL and here is the insert statement

```
create table employee_pay_tbl
( 
    EMP_ID          varchar(9)   NOT NULL  primary key, 
    position        VARCHAR(15)  not null ,
    date_hire        date, 
    pay_rate         decimal (4,2),
    date_last_raise  date, 
    salary           decimal (8,2),    
    bonus            decimal (6,2),
    constraint  EMP_FK FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_TBL(EMP_ID) 
);
```

This is the insert statement that's not working

```
INSERT INTO employee_pay_tbl 
VALUES ('442346889','TEAM LEADER','2000-06-17','14.75','2009-06-01','NULL','NULL');
```

I tried to identify the offending value using this piece of code

```
SELECT * FROM employee_pay_tbl WHERE isnumeric(bonus) = 0 AND bonus IS NOT null;
```

I think the Date value is causing the error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting varchar all over where it expects decimal, delete the quotes aroud the values for decimal columns, try:

```
INSERT INTO employee_pay_tbl VALUES ('442346889', 'TEAM LEADER', '2000-06-17', 14.75, '2009-06-01', NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the insert to use `NULL` instead of `'NULL'`

```
INSERT INTO employee_pay_tbl 
VALUES ('442346889','TEAM LEADER','2000-06-17','14.75','2009-06-01',NULL,NULL);
```

Also, make it a habbit to specify the column names, so that if the table structure changes, it does not break your query.

Something like

```
INSERT INTO employee_pay_tbl (EMP_ID, position, date_hire, pay_rate, date_last_raise, salary, bonus)
VALUES ('442346889','TEAM LEADER','2000-06-17','14.75','2009-06-01',NULL,NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting `NULL`  try this

For `decimal` value you can try without single quotes

```
INSERT INTO employee_pay_tbl
VALUES ('442346889',
        'TEAM LEADER',
        '2000-06-17',
         14.75,
        '2009-06-01',
        NULL,
        NULL);
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a7b3/1)

A better approach you can specify columnname like

```
insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3 ) values (value1,value2.value3);
```